# Get playlist items published before and after a certain point - Youtube API V3

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have a PHP script that processes parameters, converts them to relevant YAPIV3 params and turns it into a query string for the YouTube API V3.

A sample string can be:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus&maxResults=50&playlistId=UU-S6cXyil4qbIPfb2hrcH4w&key=AIzaSyDpFFK1zQpXvUgOghKYriA9LYtrI-B9QLc&publishedBefore=2016-12-03T15:20:54+00:00&publishedAfter=2016-11-28T15:20:54+00:00
```

However, unlike the search `list` documentation the `publishedBefore` and `publishedAfter` aren't accepted parameters.

All I want to do is get a list of a users videos between two points.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Can anyone suggest a query string using `/v3/search` service to achieve what I'd like to do?